# How do I concatenate a previous value to a new value in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have looked around on both google and on stackoverflow and haven't found much the main problem I think is I don't exactly know how to word the question correctly, so If you have come across this before please point me in the right direction.

### The situation.

Basically I have a bunch of records lets say that hold image paths "image.jpg", "another.jpg", "foo.png", "bar.gif".
I need to prepend a path onto these so when I call the record I get something like "assets/image.jpg", "assets/another.jpg", "assets/foo.png", "assets/bar.gif".

I need to select the file name of all the images and update them with this amended version.

Get all the filenames

```
SELECT 'Filename' FROM 'File' WHERE 1
```

Update them with the new filename

```
UPDATE 'File' SET 'Filename' = 'assets/'+'Filename'
```

Obviously this second part doesn't work.

If anyone could give me insight as to if this is possible and how to acomplish it if it is that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to wrap column name and table name with single quotes as they are identifiers.

And use `CONCAT()` function to concatenate string.

```
UPDATE File SET Filename = CONCAT('assets/', Filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `character instead of ' for field names so your query should be
UPDATE`file`SET`Filename`= 'assets' +`Filename`